# Are this simple claim and its proof correct?

Tags: mean, law-of-large-numbers, inequality

Suppose random sequence $\{X_{i}(N)\}_{i=1}^{N}$ is a row-wise i.i.d. triangular array, where $N$ is sample size. This means for any given $N$, $X_{i}(N),\dots,X_{N}(N)$ are i.i.d. following distribution $F_{N}$. Suppose $\sqrt{N}E(X_{i}(N))=o(1)$ and $var(X_{i}(N))=o(1)$, then $m_N=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i}X_{i}(N)=o_{p}(N^{-1/2})$.

We try to prove it by showing that $\sqrt{N}m_N=o_{p}(1)$ using Chebyshev's inequality. As $N\rightarrow \infty$, it holds that

$$Pr(|\sqrt{N}m_N-\sqrt{N}E(m_{N})|>k)=Pr(|\sqrt{N}m_N-o(1)|>k)\leq \frac{var(\sqrt{N}m_{N})}{k^2}=\frac{Nvar(X_{i}(N))}{Nk^2}=o(1)$$.

Does this look correct? Thanks!

Comment: The double subscripting and the explicit upper bound of $N$ are confusing.  Don't you want to contemplate an *infinite* sequence of random variables?  And do you perhaps mean to assume $\sqrt{N_i}E(X_{N_i})=o(1)$?

Comment: @whuber Thanks! I see your point. Yes, I meant an infinite sequence of random variables. What I tried to say here is that the distribution of $X_i$ will change with sample size $N$ ( Or in a different notation $\{X_i(N)\}_{i=1}^N$ is a rowwise i.i.d. triangular array). Let me try to modify the notation.

Comment: Since your variables are iid along rows that's correct. You'd otherwise want to be careful about whether  the order notation was uniform in $i$ or not: eg $i/N$ is $o(1)$  for fixed $i$, but not uniformly in $i$.

Comment: @ThomasLumley Thanks! That's helpful.